# Rpi Python interfacing RS232 to RS485 Converter Problem

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am establishing serial communication using raspberry Pi with ADAM-4520 device using pyserial lib using usb to serial converter.
1st,I tested device with PC using hyper terminal and with Pi using Gtkterm,
To read sensor values from device with command "#04".
Here i first giving output from Gtkterm.

```
#04
>+261.25+310.76+049.09+206.77+126.80+049.79

#04
>+261.25+310.76+049.09+206.75+126.80+049.79
```

But when i am trying through Pyserial program it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
import serial
import time
s=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
                baudrate=9600,
                parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                timeout=1)
st="#04"
st=''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in st)
x=st.encode('ascii')
while True:
   s.write(x)
   print(x)
   time.sleep(0.2)
   text=s.readline()
   temp=text.decode('ascii')
   #text=text.decode('utf-8')
      #text=text[5:-1]
   print(temp)
   time.sleep(2)
```

As both hyper terminal and gtkterm work with ascii ,i am also tried to convert my command into ascii also but no result.
i am new to python ,please guide to find the issue guys

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 helloworld.py
b'354852'

b'354852'

b'354852'
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the Adam but I doubt you need to do that encode('ascii').  I think its more likely that the Adam is waiting for a line termination. Try st='#04\r' or '#04\r\n' (where '\r' is a carriage return and '\n' is a newline.

Comment: @electrogas,Thanks for your suggestion.Its really helped and my code start working with `(st="#04\r")`.